# Download JPG from API link and give it a variable name

Tags: json, wordpress, image, api, rest

I'm a total amateur regarding coding and API and my question might appear totally stupid to most of you advanced coders, but I can't help myself:

I have got a file which contains API links. I can access these API links over an OAuth2 token which was provided to me by the creator of the API. My goal is to download the images, to which the API links me, and give them a certain name, in detail, the SKU of the article (which is available in the API link). The API links look like this: https://api.vlb.de/api/v1/cover/9783416040785/m. The part after /cover/ is the SKU of the article (book) and has to be the name of the image file. Since I have more than 500 images to download from the API link and upload to my FTP server to use WP All Import to add these images as product images, I don't want to do this manually and I can't imagine that there is no way to bulk-download and rename images available on API links.

So my question is: how can I bulk download images from API links and give them names according to a variable which the API link contains?

Thanks a whole lot in advance!

Comment: You should show us what you tried and where you got stuck. Doing HTTP requests, adding a header and storing the result in a file are pretty common tasks so this can definitely be done.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. A friend of mine already coded something for me. Thread can be closed. :)